# Discord.py: Purge command raising CommandError

Tags: python, discord.py

For whatever reason, 2 weeks later my completely untouched code for my purge command in my bot stopped working. Upon inspecting it, there seems to be absolutely nothing wrong with it.

Here is what I have:

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
@commands.command(aliases=['Purge', 'delete', 'del', 'clear', 'clr'])
async def purge(self, ctx, amount):
  limit = amount # amount you're deleting
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit+1) # uses the argument for the amount to actually delete the messages
  await ctx.send(str(amount) + " messages have been deleted.", delete_after=5.0) # sends how many messages were deleted
```

Comment: What is type of error? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: Its in the title, It's literally just "CommandError"

Comment: Can you show the entire error? CommandError is too vague and can be raised for multiple reasons, showing how you invoke it could also be helpful.

Comment: There is nothing for me to show I know what you mean, is it an error like ArgumentParsingError, TooManyArguments, etc but it literally only said CommandError. It didn't say anything else. To invoke it, you simple run the command normal e.i `(prefix)purge #`

Comment: Errors normally aren’t that vague and short, most of the time they provide a useful description, please reproduce the error again and post the **full** traceback, otherwise there’s not much that can be done here.

Comment: `channel.purge()` takes an `int`, so you may want to change your amount to `amount:int` and see if that helps

Comment: @Bagle That actually fixed it! Thank you. Can you make that an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that [`channel.purge()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=channel%20purge#discord.TextChannel.purge) takes an `int`. One way you can solve this problem is by immediately converting the author's `amount` argument into an `int` (as seen in the short example below).

```py
@commands.command()
async def purge(self, ctx, amount:int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(amount=amount+1)
```